# How to effectively curate expert content?

Tags: discussion

This is meant to collect ideas on how non-novices can use this SE with minimal distraction from novice and trivial content (aka fluff). Currently it seems that watch/ignore lists are the only means, but is there any other alternative?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way of doing so, not because of the excessive "novice" questions, but rather because of the lack of actual good chess content on this site

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254129/do-users-upvote-out-of-sympathy-and-how-should-that-be-addressed (LQ quality -> experts being pushed away -> SE = beginners upvote fest)

Comment: I see a lot of arrogance in that post

Comment: Yet it highlights the worst-case scenario that can happen without sufficient quality control. Upvotes here mean nothing for questions even if they are +10 or more (in fact it could be just 10 beginners upvoting crap), same goes for user reputation that serves more as participation points - especially when you compare 1k and 10k users, none is necessarily more of an expert. If people have to sieve out highly voted content, how is this site even better than Quora?

Comment: Are you a Grandmaster? Because otherwise I think it's a bit unfair to complain about the "low quality of beginner's criteria)

Comment: @David you don't need to be a GM here to realize how the site is drawing in more novices than anything else

Answer (score 2):

I guess one could write a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/tags/script) to filter out content you don't want to see in the question lists. But I'm struggling on how effective rules can be designed:

- Filtering on reputation seems a reasonable first step, but sometimes users with high reputation users post trivial content, and sometimes new users post really interesting questions - do you really want to exclude those?
- You already mentioned ignoring tags; those questions are grayed out by default but you can actually [*hide* them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321052/295232) via the sidebar widget. Click the 'edit' link to do so:

[image]

Generally speaking, I can usually determine from the question title whether a question is interesting for me or not. If not, I just don't click on it. That's an attitude change rather than a system change, but it works for me.